# Why is the h in OHG "riohhan" geminated?

Tags: history, old-high-german

Why is the "h" in the [Old High German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_High_German) word "riohhan" ([riechen](https://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/riechen), Engl. "to smell", [cognate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate) with Engl. "to reek") [geminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination)?

Answer (score 5):

The underlying Germanic form was *reuk-a*, according to Kluge's etymological dictionary.  Then, in the beginning of the [High German consonant shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_consonant_shift#Phase_1), which set apart Old High German from the other Germanic languages, voiceless plosives /p t k/ regularly became geminated fricatives /ff ss xx/ **in intervocalic position**, which we have in *reuka*.  The <hh> is only a spelling of this /xx/.  (In some other positions, the plosives turned into the affricates /pf ts kx/.)

Parallel examples of the same phenomenon are

> *makon* > *mahhôn* "make"

> *reikeis* (actually got.) > *rîhhi* "rich"

The existence of the geminated fricatives is nothing unusual, they appearently had existed before in Germanic (in contrast to the affricates), according to my reference (Wilhelm Schmidt: "Geschichte der deutschen Sprache", 2007).  The shift was a long process, though, and the concrete form /riohhan/ is only one snapshot out of some centuries.

Now, *why* the consonant shift occured is difficult to say and still researched.  It probably started in some corner of the language and then proceeded by chain shift effects.

Comment: What about bi**z**an /bite/ not bi**zz**an, la**z**an /let/ not la**zz**an ?

Comment: Kluge lists the OHD forms as /bîz(z)an/ and /lâz(z)an/, so appearently both forms are documented. Long consonants after long vowels got phonetically shortened quite early, though (as Schmidt writes in section 2.3.3.4 on OHD gemination).

Answer (score -2):

It is not geminated. The word contains two separate h's in to separate syllables. Geminated consonants exist only within the same syllable.

The first h is a length marker that will not be pronounced. It still exists in modern standard German at the end of some syllables and is called [Dehnungs-h](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehnungs-h):

> Floh, früh, Vieh, ...

The second h is the first consonant of the next syllable. Also in modern standard German it can happen, that a syllable, that ends with a *Dehnungs-h* meets a syllable that begins with the consonant h:

> Strohhut, Schuhhaus, Gehhilfe, Kuhhandel, Frühherbst, Viehhandel, ...

Comment: This answer does not seem to take into account that the question is about Old High German.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Well observed. But the question in fact has nothing to do with OHG. It is the same effect in old and modern versions of German

Comment: That doesn't make sense. *H* did not indicate vowel length in OHG; in the given context, it represents /x/.